# UI testing of a UIKeyCommand added via keyCommands

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I have freshly added a bunch of key commands (Cmd-..., etc) in the app by implementing

```
-(NSArray<UIKeyCommand*>*)keyCommands;
```

on a UIViewController subclass. Everything works wonderfully when manually tested in the app. The problem is how to UI test this in the iOS simulator.

I don't seem to be able invoke these commands using a method on `XCUIElement`. According to [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement?language=objc), there only seems to be one text input method on iOS

```
- (void)typeText:(NSString *)text;
```

with no (apparent) way to bless the input character with a key modifier flag (`XCUIKeyModifierFlags`) for `Cmd`, `Alt`, etc keys.

The method

```
- (void)typeKey:(NSString *)key modifierFlags:(XCUIKeyModifierFlags)flags;
```

appears to be macOS only. It would be a shame to provide these commands but not be able to test them in our UI testing suite.

Any ideas that can help me make some progress would be hugely welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard input of the iphone emulator requires some settings. Make sure you currently select the simulator, and then set it in the upper left corner toolbar:

1. `I/O` -> `Input` -> `Send Keyboard Input to Device`
2. `I/O` -> `Keyboard` -> `Connect Hardware Keyboard`